# PHP page only works when launched from compiler

Tags: php, webmatrix

I created a real time plot with flot and I made it work finally but there is one particularity: It only works if I launch the page from WebMatrix IDE.
This code has a PHP script to acquire data and then plot it. When I'm on the IDE, I use the option "*preview in browser*" and it works but if I close WebMatrix, go to the folder and double click to start "index.php" on Firefox it does not work.
Why is that?

Comment: PHP has to be ran through a web server.  If you just open the file like a regular file to view it, it won't work, as you describe.

Comment: Do you have a server running?

Comment: I have IIS. Should work right?

Comment: IIS should work, though it is famous for annoying problems. Anyway, you have to configure it to interpret php scripts _and_ you have to request the php script via its http url, _not_ via its file system path which you can also browse with a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't running a server. PHP is a server-side scripting language, and as such it needs to run on a server to do anything. Google "Apache web server" or alternatively "IIS web server".

Comment: You can use php without an http server.

Comment: @arkascha not if you're trying to view the file in a browser

Comment: Certainly you can. For example when using an FPM. But I agree that this is not what the OP is looking for. I only posted the comment because I dislike those absolute answers.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side scripting language. You can't just open the file like an static HTML webpage. You should use a web-server (such as XAMPP) to view it correctly.

Your WebMatrix IDE previews your file correctly because it process the PHP file for it's output.

Comment: XAMPP isn't a server, it's a package of Apache, MySQL and various other things

Comment: And you certainly can use php without an http server. You can configure your system to open a php file using the php interpreter upon a double click. But I agree that _most likely_ this is not what the OP is looking for.